# Remember or Remind?

Tags: word-choice

> 1. I hope he's reminded to buy some food. There is nothing left in the refrigerator.
> 2. I hope he's remembered to buy some food. There is nothing left in the refrigerator.

Which's wrong?

Comment: he's remembered = he **has** remembered; he's reminded = he **is** reminded (i.e. someone reminds him)

Comment: In casual speech, many native speakers wouldn't articulate the **/w/** of **was** in contexts like #1, which could thus represent *I hope he **was** reminded to buy some food [by someone unspecified].*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: the distinction I'm trying to make is between the active and passive; whether it is "is" or "was" is not relevant to that distinction. But I cannot say that I've ever seen **he's** as a contraction for **he was**.

Comment: @TRomano: Sure - we never *write* **'s** to indicate that particular "reduction", but I think it's fairly common in actual *speech* among Anglophones everywhere.

Comment: It's not done by speakers of my particular dialect (Central Atlantic, per D.A.R.E.). We have a protruding-lips W. (wooder = water, like some Irish accents).  But I do hear it often from speakers south of us.

Answer (score 4):

Neither is wrong. They mean different things.

To be reminded means that somebody or something brings the thought to mind. It implies that you had either forgotten to buy food or, at least, were not thinking about it.

> > There was a note on the fridge to remind me to buy some food.
> >
> > My friend reminded me as I went out that I had to buy some food.

To remember means to keep it in mind. You were aware all along that you needed to buy food. You did not need reminding.

> > Did you remember to buy some food? Of course, how could I forget that we wanted pizza for dinner.
> >
> > I remembered that apart from washing the car I had to buy some food as I returned home.